# How to Decrypt and Use Encrypted Response in Ktor HTTP Client

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, ktor-client

I'm working on an Android application where I need to encrypt the request body before sending it to the server and then decrypt the response received from the server. I'm using Ktor's HTTP client for network requests and I have a **`CryptoUtils`** class that handles encryption and decryption using AES. Here's an outline of what I have done:

1. Encryption: I have successfully installed a plugin to encrypt the request body before it's sent to the server. Here's the code for the encryption install (this exemple is for login only, i willl make it global later):

```
private fun HttpClientConfig<OkHttpConfig>.encryptionInstall() {
    install("EncryptRequest") {
        requestPipeline.intercept(HttpRequestPipeline.Transform) { request ->
            if (request !is EmptyContent) {
                val request = request as LoginDTO
                val originalBody = Json.encodeToString(x)
                val encryptionKey = "MY_ENCRYPTION_KEY"
                val encryptedBody = CryptoUtils.encryptData(
                    encryptionKey, originalBody
                )
                val encryptedContent = TextContent(encryptedBody, ContentType.Application.Json)
                proceedWith(encryptedContent)
            } else {
                proceedWith(request)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. encryption: Now, I'm trying to decrypt the response received from the server using the **`DecryptResponse`** plugin. Here's the code for the decryption install:

```
private fun HttpClientConfig<OkHttpConfig>.decryptInstall() {
    install("DecryptResponse") {
        receivePipeline.intercept(HttpReceivePipeline.After) { response ->
            val originalResponseReceived = response.body<String>()
            runCatching {
                val encryptionKey = "MY_DECRYPTION_KEY"
                val decryptData = CryptoUtils.decryptData(
                    encryptionKey, originalResponseReceived.toString().replace("\n", "")
                )
                val castedFromStringToObject =
                    Json.decodeFromString<LoginResponseDTO>(decryptData.orEmpty())
                // Now I have the decrypted data, how do I proceed with it?
                // I need to create an HttpResponse object with this decrypted data.
                // But I can't create an instance of an abstract class HttpResponse.
                // How can I create a new HttpResponse to proceed with the decrypted data?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried decrypting the response using the DecryptResponse plugin and I successfully decrypted the content. However, I encountered an issue when trying to proceed with the decrypted data. Since HttpResponse is an abstract class, I couldn't directly create an instance of it to proceed with the decrypted data.

I was expecting to be able to create a new HttpResponse object with the decrypted data so that I can continue processing it. However, since HttpResponse is abstract, I'm not sure how to proceed. I need guidance or examples on how to create a new HttpResponse to proceed with the decrypted data after decryption.

Any insights or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking for examples, please just have a look at the actual [source code](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/ef29b8810ef50a9879dd13fd4d542a35ec6119ae/ktor-client/ktor-client-plugins/ktor-client-encoding/common/src/ContentEncoding.kt#L138).
This is phase `HttpResponsePipeline.Receive`, but still the `HttpResponsePipeline`.

```
scope.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Receive) { (type, content) ->
    val method = context.request.method
    val contentLength = context.response.contentLength()
    if (contentLength == 0L) return@intercept
    if (contentLength == null && method == HttpMethod.Head) return@intercept
    if (content !is ByteReadChannel) return@intercept
    val response = with(plugin) {
        HttpResponseContainer(type, context.decode(context.response, content))
    }
    proceedWith(response)
}
```

File [`HttpResponsePipeline`](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/statement/HttpResponsePipeline.kt) should have been read, because understanding the phases is crucial.
The situation might be easier to understand and debug, when also adding a logging interceptor.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-client-logging-native
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:1.3.1")
```

When intercepting at phase `HttpReceivePipeline.After`, this should be a plain-text response already (!!). With multiple interceptors it becomes obvious why selecting the proper phase is important. Phase `After` appears too late, see [`HttpResponsePipeline`](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.statement/-http-response-pipeline/-phases/index.html); `Receive`, `Transform` or `Parse` appear more meaningful than `After`. When using `Transform` on the request side already, I'd suggest to also use it on the response side.

---

You may want to return an instance of [`DefaultHttpResponse`](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.statement/-default-http-response/index.html) or maybe [`HttpResponseContainer`](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.statement/-http-response-container/index.html). See what `proceedWith()` at phase `HttpResponsePipeline.Transform` would accept to know which return-type is required. Even when the original `response` is immutable, you still can/should copy the headers from the original `response` (except content-lenght) + the decrypted `response.body`.

As the statement `response = with(plugin)` suggests, one could [plug-in](https://ktor.io/docs/client-custom-plugins.html) the code, while overriding hooks `transformRequestBody` and `transformResponseBody`. This might be the proper approach.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, when I use responsePipeline with Phase Transform, I will have the response as a ByteBufferChannel and when I try to cast it I will end up with castException

Comment: Give up on casting, you have to construct there. Just see the example above, `content instanceof ByteBufferChannel`, while the `response` to return is being constructed by passing it into `HttpResponseContainer`. Statement `context.decode(context.response, content)`, which reads the byte-buffer, might be `instanceof String`.

Comment: All that is required to return to the interceptor-chain is `val response = with(plugin) {  HttpResponseContainer(type, context.decode(context.response, content)) }` and `proceedWith(response)`... that's also why I'd say that en encryption plugin would make sense, because the plugin API exposes the required hooks.